# request response with activemq - always send double response

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

I'm new at activeMq. I tried to create a simple request response like this.

```
    public Listener(string destination)
    {
        // set factory
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory(URL);
        IConnection connection;
        try
        {
            connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            connection.Start();

            ISession session = connection.CreateSession();

            // create consumer for designated destination
            IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(new Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Commands.ActiveMQQueue(destination));

            consumer.Listener += new MessageListener(consumer_Listener);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            throw new Exception("Exception in Listening ", ex);
        }
    }
```

The OnMessage

```
    static void consumer_Listener(IMessage message)
    {

        IConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616/");
        using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            //Create the Session
            using (ISession session = connection.CreateSession())
            {
                //Create the Producer for the topic/queue
                // IMessageProducer prod = session.CreateProducer(new Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Commands.ActiveMQTempQueue(message.NMSDestination));

                IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(message.NMSDestination);

                // Create Response
                // IMessage response = session.CreateMessage();
                ITextMessage response = producer.CreateTextMessage("Replied from VS2010 Test");

                //response.NMSReplyTo = new Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Commands.ActiveMQQueue("testQ1");
                response.NMSCorrelationID = message.NMSCorrelationID;

                if (message.NMSReplyTo != null)
                {
                    producer.Send(message.NMSReplyTo, response);
                    Console.WriteLine("Receive: " + ((ITextMessage)message).NMSCorrelationID);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received from : " + message.NMSDestination.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------");
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Every time i tried to send a request to the listener, the response always send repeatedly. The first response will have NMSReplyTo properties while the other not.

My workaround to stop this situation by cheking the NMSReplyTo properties

```
                if (message.NMSReplyTo != null)
                {
                    producer.Send(message.NMSReplyTo, response);
                    Console.WriteLine("Receive: " + ((ITextMessage)message).NMSCorrelationID);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received from : " + message.NMSDestination.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------");
                }
```

In my understanding, this happened because there was a circular send response in the listener to the same Queue.

Could you guys help me how to fix this?

Many Thanks, 
Chris

Answer (score 2):

This problem solved by use the same session for listener and producer response . 
In my code, i used different session for listening and producer response hence create the circular loop.

With creating a single session, this problem solved.
feel free to comment on this ;)

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

You sample is a bit incomplete as you don't show what all the Destination names are you are using but it looks like you have the consumer create a producer in its onMessage callback that produces to the same queue as the original consumer, which would of course create a circular loop.  Can you give a full example or better explain what it is you are trying to accomplish here?

Regards
Tim.
www.fusesource.com

Comment: Hi Tim; The destination parameter is the queue name, use as a constructor parameter so i could make a listener for one queue.

What i would like to do is a listener that monitor the designation queue and then response it with sending a message.

hope that helps, and thanks for the response Tim. :)

Comment: In general request / response involves two separate destinations, one is usually a standard topic or queue which receives the request and the other is the usually a temporary destination that the request handler sends the response to.  Sending the request and response on the same destination is what's getting you into circular loops.